# \includegraphics optional argument not resolved if macro

Tags: macros, graphics

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\scalefactor}{scale = 0.25}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
  \centering
  %Next line does not work
  \includegraphics[\scalefactor]{image}
  % The following line works
  %\includegraphics[scale = 0.25]{image}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Output:

```
! Package keyval Error: scale = 0.25 undefined.
```

I need to scale a number of images by the same factor, hence the command.

1. How to solve this and more importantly
2. Why is this only specific to `\includegraphics`

Comment: You can see why it's a problem if you use `\expandafter\includegraphics\expandafter[\scalefactor]{image}` which is longer than the intented shortcut.

Comment: It's not specific only of `\includegraphics` but of most (if not all) arguments that consist of key=value options.

Comment: @percuße I don't use this directly, it is nested in another macro, will using `\expandafter` hurt the general case? If not clear please let me know I will edit the question

Comment: The problem here is that the key=value algorithm has to see the `=` to split both parts. If it is included in a macro it can see it and therefore the whole macro is incorrectly taken as one value-less key, which is of course not defined.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this way:

```
\newcommand{\scalefactor}{.25}
\includegraphics[scale=\scalefactor]{image}
```

Comment: ooh I was just saying that your posted 10 seconds before my edit went on so + 1 :-)

Answer (score 8):

If you use

```
\setkeys{Gin}{scale=0.25}
```

that key value will be in force by default until you change it, so there is no need to use a LaTeX command macro syntax here.

If your issue is that you want to set the value somewhere else you can go

```
\newcommand{\scalefactor}{0.25}
...
\includegraphics[scale = \scalefactor]{image}
```

Comment: As far as I understand this is global scaling factor. If this is the case, then this wont work for me because I scale only specific images

Comment: well it's local to the current environment or group, or you can set it back to 1 explicitly, or if it really is only sporadic images what's wrong with `[scale=.25]`

Comment: aetting back to 1 is a good idea. They are sporadic, all images must be scaled by the same factor. I am currently adding images as I go. If I get `Overfull` then I step down the scaling a notch.

Comment: @aiao `scale` is not the right key for solving the overfull line problems. Use `width=\columnwidth` or `width=.9\textwidth` (adjust the factor to suit).

Comment: @egreg but that would mess up the scaling ratio __across images__, which is imporatant in my case

Answer (score 1):

Defining a private `\includegraphics` allows you to call macros as optional arguments:

```
\protected\def\newincludegraphics{\@testopt\new@includegraphics{}}
\def\new@includegraphics[#1]{%
  \begingroup
  \@protected@edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\includegraphics
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else[#1]\fi
   }\x
}

\newincludegraphics[\scalefactor]{image}
```

Comment: but if you want to do this you should probably at least use `\@protected@edef` rather than `\edef` but even then it makes the argument a "moving argument" in which fragile commands will break. The keyval parser goes to a lot of effort to avoid that, and this disables all of that mechanism.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: Thanks. Do you have examples of the possibly fragile arguments? I haven't come across them in `\includegraphics`. The values of keys or a file to be inserted?

Comment: well you can go `width=\ifdim\Gin@nat@width>\textwidth \textwidth \else \Gin@nat@width\fi` to set the size to be natural size or textwidth, but that relies on `\ifdim` not being expanded during the keyval parsing and as I say the parser is designed so that it works.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: OK, thanks. I will leave the answer with `\@protected@edef`. Most likely the OP didn't intend to call fragile commands in the optional argument.

Comment: I am getting this error: ``ERROR: You can't use `\spacefactor' in vertical mode.`` Anybody has an idea?

Comment: Use `\makeatletter` <your code> `\makeatother`.