# keyval error on passing macro as an optional argument to includegraphics

Tags: graphics, optional-arguments

I am trying to include an image in my document:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\def\foo{scale=0.1}
\includegraphics[\foo]{fig1.eps}

\end{document}
```

gives me the error

```
ERROR: Package xkeyval Error: `scale=0.1' undefined in families `Gin'.
```

It has something to do with macro expansion, but I was not able to solve it. Then I saw [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97343/includegraphics-optional-argument-not-resolved-if-macro) question with the following answer

> Defining a private `\includegraphics` allows you to call macros as
>   optional arguments:
>
> ```
> \protected\def\newincludegraphics{\@testopt\new@includegraphics{}}
> \def\new@includegraphics[#1]{%
>   \begingroup
>   \@protected@edef\x{\endgroup
>     \noexpand\includegraphics
>     \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else[#1]\fi
>    }\x
> }
>
> \newincludegraphics[\scalefactor]{image}
> ```

where the new macro `\newincludegraphics` was defined.

**MWE**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\protected\def\newincludegraphics{\@testopt\new@includegraphics{}}
\def\new@includegraphics[#1]{%
  \begingroup
  \@protected@edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\includegraphics
    \if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else[#1]\fi
   }\x
}

\def\foo{scale=0.1}
\newincludegraphics[\foo]{fig1.eps}

\end{document}
```

Nevertheless I still get this error:

```
ERROR: You can't use `\spacefactor' in vertical mode.

--- TeX said ---
\@->\spacefactor 
                 \@m 
l.62 \newincludegraphics
                        [scale=0.1]{fig1.eps}
```

What could be the cause of this error, and is there a workaround without defining another macro to include graphics?

Comment: You need \makeatletter just before your new command due to the @ letter

Comment: rather than `\def\foo{scale=0.1}` the intended usage is that you use `\setkeys{Gin}{scale=0.1}` ... `\includegraphics{fg1}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am changing the scale this way, but for some reason it doesn't have an effect.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer I tried every combination of ``\makeatletter`` and ``\makeatother`` but cannot seem to make it work, would you care to post an answer?

Comment: oops:-) http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/164116/which-arguments-of-includegraphics-cannot-be-set-beforehand/164132#164132

Comment: @DavidCarlisle but does that make a global change? In that case, I only want to change the scale for that figure. What is the most elegant option here?

Comment: possible as you had it originally but `\expandafter\includegraphics\expandafter[\foo]{fig1.eps}` ro expand `\foo` first.

Comment: Indeed, I was trying to use that without success till I realized the problem was with a new line (literally, not \newline) I put in a macro after \edef. So this solved my problem: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/7453/what-is-the-use-of-percent-signs-at-the-end-of-lines

Comment: @DavidCarlisle If you can post ``\expandafter\includegraphics\expandafter[\foo]{fig1.eps}`` as an answer, I can mark it. But I also think this question might be a duplicate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the keyval parser does not expand macros, but you can do

\expandafter\includegraphics\expandafter[\foo]{fig1.eps}

to expand `\foo` first if you need to.

Answer (score 4):

You can define a new key:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\define@key{Gin}{foo}[]{\setkeys{Gin}{scale=0.1}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[foo]{example-image.pdf}

\end{document}
```

The second argument to `\setkeys` is not expanded, and the optional argument to `\includegraphics` like in

```
\includegraphics[<whatever>]{file}
```

is basically managed as `\setkey{Gin}{<whatever>}`.