# How to expand a macro into viewport= arguments(includegraphics)

Tags: graphics, expansion, crop

How do I properly expand a macro `\myviewport` so that it is parsed as the `viewport=0pt 10pt 100pt 200pt` argument of `\includegraphics[clip, \myviewport]{somepdf.pdf}`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\aport}{45.29pt 86.28pt 235pt 187pt}
\includegraphics[clip, viewport={\aport}]{somepdf.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Error: `! Argument of \Gread@parse@vp has an extra }.`
My simple idea was based on
[\includegraphics optional argument not resolved if macro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/97343/includegraphics-optional-argument-not-resolved-if-macro)

What does work is giving individual macros for each viewport value:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}
\begin{document}
\newlength{\Xoffset}
\setlength{\Xoffset}{35pt}
\newlength{\myl}
\setlength{\myl}{235pt - \Xoffset}
\newcommand*{\lux}{200pt}
\includegraphics[clip, viewport=10pt 50pt \lux{} \the\myl{}, page=3]{somepdf.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Note that `\myl` is a length and `\lux` is a "string".

In the long run I'd like to automate the cropping of some pdf files (which have Media Boxes not starting at 0 0):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}

\newlength{\Xoffset}
\newlength{\Yoffset}
\newcommand*{\setpdfoffset}[2]{
    \setlength{\Xoffset}{#1}
    \setlength{\Yoffset}{#2}
}
\newcommand*{\aviewport}{} %set an empty default
\setpdfoffset{0pt}{0pt} %set a default

\newcommand*{\setviewport}[4]{
    \newlength{\mylux}\setlength{\mylux}{#1-\Xoffset}
    \newlength{\myluy}\setlength{\myluy}{#2-\Yoffset}
    \newlength{\myrox}\setlength{\myrox}{#3-\Xoffset}
    \newlength{\myroy}\setlength{\myroy}{#4-\Yoffset}
    \renewcommand*{\aviewport}{viewport={\the\mylux} {\the\myluy}  {\the\myrox}  {\the\myroy}}
}
\begin{document}

%in Windows command line:
% pdfinfo -box somepdf.pdf |awk "/MediaBox/ {print; print \"Xoffset=\"$2 \" Yoffset=\"$3\"\n\"; print \"\\newlength{\\Xoffset}\\setlength{\\Xoffset}{\"$2\"pt} \\newlength{\\Yoffset}\\setlength{\\Yoffset}{\"$3\"pt}\"}"

\setpdfoffset{35.29pt}{36.28pt}
\setviewport{45.29pt}{86.28pt}{235pt}{187pt}
\emph{\aviewport}
\fbox{\includegraphics[clip, \aviewport{}, page=2]{somepdf}
\end{document}
```

Error: `keyval: viewport={10.0pt} {50.0pt} {199.71pt} {150.72pt} undefined. ...lip, \aviewport]{somepdf}}`

XeLaTeX is my first choice, but pdfLaTeX doesn't like this code either.

Bonus: Get the X and Y Offset values for `\setpdfoffset` by using `\input{|"pdfinfo -box somepdf.pdf |awk ..."}`, but this is an escaping question and not an expanding.

Comment: Note that there are two subtly different issues here. Hiding the `key=value` part in a macro breaks in general with keyval methods as the parser for keys doesn't see the right name: that's general and not dependent on the key involved. Here, you have a second issue as `viewport` is looking for four values separated by spaces, and again hiding stuff in a macro confuses the internals.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here are a couple of ways:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newcommand{\myviewport}{viewport=0pt 10pt 200pt 50pt}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[clip, viewport=0pt 10pt 200pt 50pt]{example-image}

\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\includegraphics[clip, \myviewport]{example-image}}\x

{\let\includegraphics\relax\xdef\x{\includegraphics[clip, \myviewport]{example-image}}}\x
\end{document}
```

The first shows what the expected output should resemble.

The second defines an expanded version `\x` of `\includegraphics[..]{...}` where `\includegraphics` is left unexpanded. It's also local as `\x` is discarded after it is used. It is very similar to

```
\edef\x{\noexpand\includegraphics[clip, \myviewport]{example-image}}\x
```

without the localization of `\x`.

The third defines a similar `\x` which is now global (also expanded, hence `\xdef`). However, in order to avoid the expansion of `\includegraphics` it is set to `\relax` within a group. That prevents it from being expanded with the call to `\xdef`, and it also survives the group. In particular `\show\x` reveals

```
> \x=macro:
->\includegraphics [clip, viewport=0pt 10pt 200pt 50pt]{example-image}.
```

The `viewport`, `trim` and `bb` (`b`ounding `b`ox) keys are special, as they *require* a specific value input. The input *has* to be in the expanded form `#1 #2 #3 #4` and is recognized using TeX's argument text or `\def`. So, if the match is not exact, incorrect arguments may be assigned to incorrect elements, causing the problem you're experiencing.

Other macros may be used in a macro-form, to an extent. As a minimum, you have to use an explicit `=`:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics[width=100pt]{example-image}

\newcommand{\mywidth}{width}%
\newcommand{\widthdimen}{100pt}%
\includegraphics[\mywidth=\widthdimen]{example-image}

%\newcommand{\mywidthkeyval}{width=100pt}%
%\includegraphics[\mywidthkeyval]{example-image}% Does not work

\includegraphics[clip, viewport=10pt 10pt 50pt 50pt]{example-image}

\newcommand{\myviewport}{viewport}%
\newcommand{\viewportvals}{10pt 10pt 50pt 50pt}%
\includegraphics[clip, \myviewport=10pt 10pt 50pt 50pt]{example-image}
%\includegraphics[clip, \myviewport=\viewportvals]{example-image}% Does not work

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perhaps you might explain a bit why expansion of both the `key=value` syntax and here the `value` itself are needed: as I've commented on the question, there are actually two related but distinct issues here as one is about `keyval`  in general and one is tied to the format of the `viewport` value.

Comment: All two versions of @Werner work. I'll stick with #1 for three reasons: a) it looks more like `\includegraphics`(compared to @steven-b-segletes); b) the macros for expanding it look a lot more readable and c) less prone to introduce stray spaces.

I'm now using three lines to define my own includegraphics 1: `newcommand*{\mygraphics}[2][]{% percent sign removes following whitespaces(e.g. generated from new lines), else they are in the document.` 2: `\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\includegraphics[clip=true, #1]{#2}}\x` 3:`}` usage `\fbox{\mygraphics[\aviewport, page=1]{example-image}}`

Answer (score 6):

The four values for options `viewport` or `trim` are identified by the separating spaces. The parser, defined for these options by package `graphicx` expects explicit spaces and fails, if the spaces are hidden inside a macro.

The following example redefines option `viewport` (in the same way option `trim` can be redefined) to expand its argument before passing the expanded value to the original option code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
% Remember original option `viewport` as `viewport@org`
\let\KV@Gin@viewport@org\KV@Gin@viewport
% Redefine option `viewport` to expand the argument and
% pass it to option `viewport@org`.
\define@key{Gin}{viewport}{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\setkeys{Gin}{viewport@org={#1}}%
  }\x
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \newcommand*{\aport}{45.29pt 86.28pt 235pt 187pt}
  \includegraphics[clip, viewport=\aport]{tiger}
\end{document}
```

The equal sign and the comma are syntax characters in LaTeX's key value lists (package `keyval` and friends). The key value parser will fail, if these characters are hidden inside macros. But it is possible to define a new option for `graphicx` with an argument that is expanded and executed again as key value list:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\makeatletter
\define@key{Gin}{expandoptions}{%
  \begingroup
  \edef\x{\endgroup
    \noexpand\setkeys{Gin}{#1}%
  }\x
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
  \newcommand*{\viewaport}{viewport=45.29pt 86.28pt 235pt 187pt, clip}
  \includegraphics[expandoptions=\viewaport]{tiger}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can define a new key for `\includegraphics`, I'll call it `xviewport`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{calc}

\makeatletter
\define@key{Gin}{xviewport}[]{%
  \begingroup\edef\x{%
    \endgroup\noexpand\setkeys{Gin}{viewport=\x@viewport}%
  }\x
}

\newlength{\Xoffset}
\newlength{\Yoffset}
\newcommand*{\setpdfoffset}[2]{%
  \setlength{\Xoffset}{#1}%
  \setlength{\Yoffset}{#2}%
}
\newcommand*{\setviewport}[4]{%
  \def\x@viewport{%
    {\the\dimexpr#1-\Xoffset} 
    {\the\dimexpr#2-\Yoffset}
    {\the\dimexpr#3-\Xoffset}
    {\the\dimexpr#4-\Yoffset}%
  }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\setpdfoffset{35.29pt}{36.28pt}
\setviewport{45.29pt}{86.28pt}{235pt}{187pt}

\fbox{\includegraphics[clip, xviewport]{example-image.pdf}}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

This works, but may not be general enough for your need:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\begin{document}
\newcommand*{\aport}{45.29pt 86.28pt 235pt 187pt}
\def\X{\includegraphics[clip, viewport=}
\expandafter\X\aport]{somepdf.pdf}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This works, but you need to be careful about whitespaces inside it: To see this, draw an \fbox{} around it:

`\fbox{\def\X{\includegraphics[clip, viewport=} \expandafter\X\aport]{example-image}}`

It adds a little white margin(approximately one character width, the space in `viewport=} \expandafter`) to the left side of the image.
The other solutions provided by @werner don't add this.
`\fbox{\begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand\includegraphics[clip, viewport = \aport]
 {example-image}}}\x}`

Comment: @nkrs True, one must be always careful of stray spaces leading up to and following a macro use.  But the actual macro use itself, as given by `\fbox{\expandafter\X\aport]{somepdf.pdf}}` introduces no stray space.