# Define variable to use in [trim = ???] in Figure environment

Tags: graphics, floats, excel

I use PDF figures that are output by Excel with excessive whitespace. There are only a few standard sizes, so I would like to define re-usable variable to set in the `[trim = ???]` option for the `\includegraphics[]{}` command.

I have tried putting this at the beginning:

```
\newcommand{\exsff}{trim = {1in 3.5in 1in 3.5in}}
```

and this when I insert the graphic:

```
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth, \exsff]{figure_name}
```

but I get an error. If I hardcode it in like this, it works:

```
\includegraphics[width=1\linewidth, trim = {1in 3.5in 1in 3.5in}]{figure_name}
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: `\setkeys{Gin}{trim=1in 3.5in 1in 3.5in}` should set the default trim setting

Comment: I don't want to set the default for the whole document. I want to have about 3 different sizes for my most common formats, and the rest I can handle individually. For example. I would like to say

[trim = \xxx],
[trim = \yyy], or
[trim = \zzz]

where I can define xxx, yyy, and zzz as a list of the four parameters I need. As in, xxx = {1in 2in 1in 2in} and so on.

Comment: The question linked as duplicate doesn't really address the problem: the solution given there, e.g. using `[scale=\scalefactor]` instead of `[\scaleconfig]`) doesn't work for `trim`. This question is rather a duplicate of https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/222043/how-to-expand-a-macro-into-viewport-argumentsincludegraphics .

Answer (score 1):

You can define new keys; here I define one, but you can do `\definetrim` as many times as you want, with different arguments.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand{\definetrim}[2]{%
  \define@key{Gin}{#1}[]{\setkeys{Gin}{trim=#2,clip}}%
}
\makeatother

\definetrim{exsff}{1in 0.5in 1in 0.5in}

\begin{document}

\includegraphics{example-image-a}

\bigskip

\includegraphics[exsff]{example-image-a}

\end{document}
```

[image]

*Production note.* I changed the values for the trimming in order to adapt them to the available example picture.