# New environment definition, to specify default overpic parameters - macro expansion and definition issues

Tags: macros, environments, expansion, includegraphics, overpic

I am endeavouring to define a new environment, which contains a nested [`overpic`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/overpic) environment, using my own set of default parameters.

My main goal is simply to have a new environment, like the below, that I can use in place of a regular `overpic`, to save my having to repeat all the below-encoded parameters.

I have been encountering myriad expansion- and brace- (or grouping) related errors. I first tried to solve this by using the [`environ`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/environ) package, as depicted below (all subsidiary macros are suitably-defined lengths, save `\figDir`, which is a path to the directory containing the image in question; these are shown in the next block of this question):

```
\NewEnviron{logoOverpic}[1]{%
    \begin{overpic}[width=\linewidth, height=\seqLogoHeight, trim=\leftTrimLogo \botTrimLogo \rightTrimLogo \topTrimLogo, clip]{\figDir/#1}
            \BODY%
    \end{overpic}%
}{}


\newcommand{\addSeqLogoLabel}[2]{
    \setcounter{putVPos}{44}

    \put (17, \value{putVPos}) {
        \fontsize{14pt}{18pt}\selectfont
        %
        % use fill colour as border as well, to get correct border-less size
        \Large\textsf{#1}\hspace*{4pt}\fboxsep0pt\fcolorbox{#2}{#2}{\phantom{X}}
    }
}
```

An example usage of this, is as follows:

```
    \begin{logoOverpic}{logoMA0466_1}
        \addSeqLogoLabel{\TFBS{CEBPB}~MA0466.1}{orange}
    \end{logoOverpic}
```

I was previously obtaining errors of the form: "Argument of \Gread@parse@vp has an extra }."

I have been trying (in vain) to resolve this, by applying a [related answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/222051/134641).

My efforts in those regards have clearly been quite poor, as they have only served to exacerbate the errors I obtain. I tried the following, though I realize it is not at all correct:

```
\NewEnviron{logoOverpic}[1]{%
    \begingroup\edef\x{\endgroup\noexpand%
    \begin{overpic}[width=\linewidth, height=\seqLogoHeight, trim=\leftTrimLogo \botTrimLogo \rightTrimLogo \topTrimLogo, clip]{\figDir/#1}}\x%
            \BODY%
    \end{overpic}%
}{}
```

I now obtain errors like the following three:

```
"Runaway argument?

‪main.tex, 396‬
clip,\@nil ,\XKV@usepresetkeys {}{presett}\let \CurrentOption \@empty \ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \Gread@parse@vp was complete.
<to be read again> 
\par 
l.396       \end{logoOverpic}
                       
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
Extra }, or forgotten \endgroup.

 
‪main.tex, 396‬
<recently read> }
 
l.396       \end{logoOverpic}
                       
I've deleted a group-closing symbol because it seems to be
spurious, as in `$x}$'. But perhaps the } is legitimate and
you forgot something else, as in `\hbox{$x}'. In such cases
the way to recover is to insert both the forgotten and the
deleted material, e.g., by typing `I$}'.
Runaway argument?

 
‪main.tex, 441‬
\env@nil \end {logoOverpic} \label {fig:0.3:JASPAR_CEBPB} \end {subfi\ETC.
! Paragraph ended before \Gread@parse@vp was complete.
<to be read again> 
\par 
l.441 
    
I suspect you've forgotten a `}', causing me to apply this
control sequence to too much text. How can we recover?
My plan is to forget the whole thing and hope for the best.
LaTeX Error: Not in outer par mode.
```

I would appreciate any suggestions that anyone might be able to offer!

---

At this stage, I do not provide a MWE. I do recognize that this makes it more difficult to assist me and apologize for any inconvenience.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions that anyone might nonetheless be willing to proffer. Should no suitable suggestions be provided within a certain interval, I will endeavour to compose a proper MWE.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've a problem with `trim=`, because you leave no space between the lengths. You can use `\newenviroment`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{overpic}

\newlength\seqLogoHeight
\newlength\leftTrimLogo
\newlength\botTrimLogo
\newlength\rightTrimLogo
\newlength\topTrimLogo

\setlength{\seqLogoHeight}{2cm}

\newenvironment{logoOverpic}[2][]
 {\begin{overpic}[
    width=\linewidth,
    height=\seqLogoHeight,
    trim={\leftTrimLogo} {\botTrimLogo} {\rightTrimLogo} {\topTrimLogo},
    clip,
    #1 % additional keys
  ]{#2}% it would be \figDir/#1 for you
 }
 {\end{overpic}}

\begin{document}

\noindent% no overfull box
\begin{logoOverpic}{example-image}
\end{logoOverpic}

\setlength{\rightTrimLogo}{4cm}

\noindent
\begin{logoOverpic}[width=4cm]{example-image}
\end{logoOverpic}

\end{document}
```

[image]